# .append() and .remove() not working in the same list - PYTHON - OOP

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, parameters

I have a problem with python.
I read 2 manuals to learn the language (Python for kids and Learn Python the Hard way) now I am trying to understand how the heck OOP works and how to use it.

I wanted to create a simple script just to learn how to handle classes and methods:

The script should allow the user to see what he has in the fridge, each item comes with a quantity and a name. Other things that the user should be able to do are: Adding items, modify their name or quantity and remove items from the "catalogue".

I tried to do it with an OOP design, since that's what I want to learn.
The problem is that the append() and remove() methods for lists are acting differently even if called to work on the same object.

Here's the code. I am sure I am doing something wrong with attributes, parameters and methods, since this is what puzzles me and drives me nuts the most about OOP

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, qty='1'):
        self.name = name
        self.qty = qty


class Fridge:
    def __init__(self):
        #create a Fridge object that is a list of stuff
        self.items = []
        #append to the list (fridge) an Item
    def add_item(self, name, qty='1'):
        self.items.append(Item(name))

    def modify_item(self):
        pass

    def remove_item(self,name, qty='0'):
        #from the items list remove Item(name))
        self.items.remove(Item(name))
```

When I call the `add_item` method with `name` and `qty` parameters in the shell the function actually adds items to the list. When I try to remove the `Item` it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#164>", line 1, in <module>
    f.remove_item('orange')
  File "C:/Users/Utente.1/Desktop/python projects/OOP/chap2 modules - packages/drill - frigorifero/fridge.py", line 22, in remove_item
    self.items.remove(Item(name))
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

but `f.items[0].name` returns
`'orange'` as a value. So `'orange'` is there and is there because the `f.add_item('orange')` method worked, but I am not able to remove it when I use the `f.remove_item('orange')` method.

What's wrong? Can you explain me not just the error but also what you think I am missing and not getting about OOP and how to improve it? It looks like a maze to me.

Comment: Why are you storing quantity as a string?

Comment: One comment on the design, I would attempt to keep item definitions and counts separate in a conceptual sense. By this I mean I would define items somehow then keep some sort of datatype that keeps track of how many of these there are. For example I would store the items as dictionary keys and have the dictionary values correspond to the item counts. This way we can get the data about how many items there are from the type of item. In this case I find the naming a bit confusing because `Item` has both the type of item *and* the information about how many of those items in the same class...

Comment: ... You can wrap that behavior up into a class and provide methods that let you access the class without having to expose that underlying mechanism/machinery to the end user of your classes. The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32997660) from Martijn Pieters gives you a nice suggestion for how you could do that with an underlying list that stores the information. Just keep in mind that if you get the design right you could change this to use other data-structures too without the end users knowing provided they are using the methods such as `remove_item` that you provided.

Comment: You are absolutely right! These are my first attempt at OOP and I am really struggling to understand things and make anything that makes sense.

So I should replace the list with a dict instead?

Comment: Well you could perhaps do that but you wouldn't necessarily have to do that. The bigger issue from a OOP design point of view is that you are trying to write your code in such a way that if you do change to a different data-structure internally the users of your classes code would not have to know about the change. Essentially if you do it correctly you can change your implementation without the end users having to change their code, this is what people mean when they talk about encapsulation.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to remove a *new* `Item()` instance from the list:

```
def remove_item(self,name, qty='0'):
    #from the items list remove Item(name))
    self.items.remove(Item(name))
```

This won't work without additional work; `Item(name)` may have the same name, but it is not equal to any of the objects already in the list. As far as Python is concerned, that object is *independent* and won't be found in the list.

You have two options:

- search through the list manually and remove the one item that has a matching name. You can do so with a list comprehension filtering out that item:

  ```
  self.items = [item for item in self.items if item.name != name]
  ```

  This in effect *keeps* everything else.
- add a [`object.__eq__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) to your `Item` class, to declare two items equal if their names are equal:

  ```
  class Item:
      def __init__(self, name, qty='1'):
          self.name = name
          self.qty = qty

      def __eq__(self, other):
          if not isinstance(other, Item):
              return NotImplemented
          return self.name == other.name
  ```

  The above implementation returns the `NotImplemented` sentinel object when comparing to something that is not itself an `Item` instance; that signals to Python to fall back to the default behaviour, which includes asking the other object if it is equal to this one.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an `Item('orange')` and then you are trying to remove another `Item('orange')`. These are two calls to `Item()` class constructor resulting in two different instances. The first one is in the list, but the second one is not.

You cannot remove a different orange than the one you've put there. This is the cause of the error.

Comment: So How do I manage to remove items that are in the items list?
How can I do to make the remove_item method work?

Comment: @user3722818: To answer the question: search the list for an element with name attribute equal to the thing you want to remove. However you don't have the qty feature implemented yet. To do that I would abandon the approach with a list and use a dict (key=name, value=quantity) instead. A remove_item could be then just an add_item with a negative quantity (plus some error handling).